# SharePoint 2013, o365 Exchange Online Task Sync

Tags: 2013, office-365

We use Office 365 for hosted exchange, and I have an on premises SharePoint 2013 farm, and I'm trying to find a way to sync tasks with Outlook.

I have been researching for the past couple days and all I've been able to find was "It's not possible yet, find a third party tool." from over a year ago, "yet" being the key word, implying that it was in the works.

[Tech Net](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/48ca4658-c667-417d-b10a-1aea244e3c84/how-can-i-sync-on-premise-sharepoint-2013-task-to-outlook-2013exchange-online-or-office-365-?forum=sharepointgeneral)

Has there been any changes with SP1, or any third party tools that will allow it to work?

Answer (score 2):

Exchange Task Sync has been completely dropped from the product. It became unavailable in SPO in November 2014 (?) and has been dropped from SharePoint Server 2016. It also requires a Sever to Server trust (S2S) which is not possible between SharePoint on-prem and Exchange Online (or visa versa).